# flutter layout rows to have columns inside

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i have a layout which i am working on but i am very new to flutter what i would like to do is
have a layout as such:

[image]

but what i have managed to do so far is this
[image]

the code for what i have managed to do is here:

```
body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  color: Colors.cyan,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Checkbox(
                        value: false,
                        onChanged: (bool? value) {
                          setState(() {
                            print(value!);
                          });
                        }, //onChanged
                      ),
                      Text("Enable 1"),
                      new Flexible(
                        child: new TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'username',
                          ),
                        ), //textfield
                      ), //flexible
                      new Flexible(
                        child: new TextField(
                          obscureText: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'password',
                          ),
                        ), //textfield
                      ), //flexible
                    ],
                  ),
                ) //Container
                ), //Expanded

            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.save_alt,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    size: 24.0,
                  ),
                  label: Text('Save'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('pressed');
                  },
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.greenAccent),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ]
)//end of body,
```

i have no idea on how to achieve my desired output any help would be appreciated

Comment: Replace the ``Row`` with ``Column`` and see your checkbox, and the two input fields down by down .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `Column` instead of the `Row`.

Then a `Row` for the text and the `checkbox` to be aligned.

Here's an example:

```
Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  color: Colors.cyan,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Checkbox(
                            value: false,
                            onChanged: (bool value) {
                              setState(() {
                                print(value);
                              });
                            }, //onChanged
                          ),
                          Text("Enable 1"),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                        child: new TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'username',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ), //flexible
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                        child: new TextField(
                          obscureText: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'password',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ), //flexible
                    ],
                  ),
                ) //Container
                ), //Expanded

            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.save_alt,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    size: 24.0,
                  ),
                  label: Text('Save'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('pressed');
                  },
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.greenAccent),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ])
```